# Foreach data in response

Tags: angular, typescript

I used to work with JSON on this way:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/SumOfDipVolume').subscribe(res => {
  for (let dipVolume of res['result']) {
    // some code
});
```

But now I don't want to hit object *result*, because my JSON object does not include *result* object. This is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "DYNAMIC DISEL 50PPM",
    "UpValue": "122,196",
    "DownValue": "-148,740.83",
    "Procentage": "45.10%"
  },
  {
    "Title": "DYNAMIC UNLEADED 95",
    "UpValue": "121,905",
    "DownValue": "-285,527.35",
    "Procentage": "29.92%"
  }
]
```

Now I must use some like this: `for (let dipVolume of res) {`
but angular tells me:
Type object is not an array type or a string type.
**How to iterate this?**

Comment: the JSON file is the data that you are getting in `res` ?

Comment: This is typescript issue `.subscribe((res: any[]) => { ... } )`

Comment: Yes man, exactly

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Parkar, your answer solved the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @NemanjaAndric added answer, Glad to know, it helped :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Typescript `type` resolving issue, it has been considered as a type of `any`(but not an array). Since you haven't specified any type, you can't loop over the object

You can solve explicitly specifying type.

```
.subscribe((res: IMyObjectShape[]) => { // preferred way to add new interface
//.subscribe((res: any[]) => { //<- use any if you're defining any interface
  ... 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are receiving all the http request if you provide the content type you will get only the result response. try by using the following code.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; 
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

serviceApi(){
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/SumOfDipVolume', {headers})
   .subscribe(res => {
       res.forEach(dipVolume =>{
        // some code
       });
   });          
}
```